# Why am I receiving an "Unassigned Local Variable" Error?

Tags: c#

Under the if statement, the bolded and italicized "CATickets" in the equation is giving me an unassigned local variable error. I'm new to coding and have no idea what this means or how to fix it. I have tried looking up this error, but again being new to coding I don't understand what is meant or how to solve it. There is not an error on the other ticket variables, so I'm not sure why this one has one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double CATickets;
            double CBTickets;
            double CCTickets;
            double totalRev;

            if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                                     "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
                CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
                CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
                CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);

                CATickets = ***CATickets*** * 15.0;
                CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
                CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
                totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

                txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
                txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
                txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
                txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");

        }

        private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_CASold.Text = "";
            txt_CBSold.Text = "";
            txt_CCSold.Text = "";
            txt_CARev.Text = "";
            txt_CBRev.Text = "";
            txt_CCRev.Text = "";
            txt_TotalRev.Text = "";
        }

        private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Codexer No, please. All that does is mask a compiler message which actually indicates that the entire logic of the code is wrong because OP forgot braces around important statements. In fact, the logic of that code block is fundamentally incorrect and needs to be fixed, instead of working around the symptoms.

Comment: I think you forgot some braces around the body of your `if` statement. The indentation suggests that the rest of the method after the `if` should only be executed if the `if` is true, but you're missing the braces around these lines which means that only the `CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);` line is executed if the `if` is true. This means that the compiler is right: `CATickets = ***CATickets*** * 15.0;` is *always* executed, but the `CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);` line *may* have been executed depending on the `if`

Comment: Pay attention: I think you are missing using parenthesis `{ }` after the if statement. If you don't put the code inside the block, all the rest starting from `CBTickets = double ...` will be executed always.

Comment: This is a great reason to use an IDE that handles code indentation standards for you.  You'd see that much of the code is indented in a way you don't expect and would spot the mistake right away.

Comment: The way you're using indentation, it suggests to my first glance that you are hoping the 11 lines of code after your `if` statement are all evaluated within that, but because you don't have any curly braces `{ }` the only line of code that will be evaluated inside the `if` statement is the very first line of code following it.

Comment: I think people can stop adding "you forgot some braces" comments now -- the first was 7 minutes ago, and we're still getting one every couple of minutes, with 4 answers always saying the same thing...

Comment: I think you forgot a `}` *wink*

Comment: "I have tried looking up this error". For real, good job doing research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some braces around the body of your `if` statement:

```
private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double CATickets;
    double CBTickets;
    double CCTickets;
    double totalRev;

    if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                             "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
    { // <-- HERE
        CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
        CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
        CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);

        CATickets = CATickets * 15.0;
        CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
        CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
        totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

        txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");
    } // <-- HERE
}
```

As it stands, your method actually looks like this (fixing the indentation to reflect what's actually happening):

```
private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double CATickets;
    double CBTickets;
    double CCTickets;
    double totalRev;

    if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                             "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
        CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
        
    CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
    CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);

    CATickets = CATickets * 15.0;
    CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
    CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
    totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

    txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
    txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
    txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
    txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");

}
```

That is, only the first line after the `if` is protected by the `if`: all of the following lines are *always* executed. As you can see, the line

```
CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
```

is *sometimes* executed (depending on the `if`), but the line

```
CATickets = CATickets * 15.0;
```

is *always* executed. Therefore the variable `CATickets` may not have been assigned when that line above is executed.

---

Since your variables are *only* used in the body of your `if`, you might as well declare them at the point that they're assigned. That helps make the problem a bit more obvious, and is generally good practice:

```
private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                             "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
    {
        double CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
        double CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
        double CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);

        CATickets = CATickets * 15.0;
        CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
        CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
        double totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

        txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don’t split declarations and initialisation. That is, don’t declare variables without a value, only to assign a value later.

Secondly, the compiler is telling you that you are using a variable which might not have been assigned. That’s because your `if` statement only applies to the line immediately following it, not to the rest, because you forgot curly braces around the following code.

Rewrite your code to fix this:

```
if (txt_CASold.Text == "" || txt_CBSold.Text == "" || txt_CCSold.Text == "") {
    return;
}

double CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text) * 15.0;
double CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text) * 12.0;
double CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text) * 9.0;
double totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");   
txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");
```

You should also remove the magic constants in your code: What’s `15.0`, etc.? Introduce named constants that explain these values.

Answer (score 0):

It means that CATickets doesn't have any value set and you are trying to use it as if it does.
It will happen if the textbox doesn't have any value in it, so CATickets is not initialized.
You already have a check to make sure there is a value in the textboxes, but you haven't used curly braces, so it only affects the following line.

To fix just add curly braces as per this excerpt:

```
    if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                             "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
    {
        CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
        CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
        CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);

        CATickets = ***CATickets*** * 15.0;
        CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
        CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
        totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

        txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block of code is missing brackets, which is why you are getting this problem. The compiler is warning you that you have not properly initialized the variables. So although the other answer on this thread is right, it is right for the wrong reason.

This if statement has no associated brackets, so it is only going to be a One-line if statement.

```
if (txt_CASold.Text != "" && txt_CBSold.Text !=
                                 "" && txt_CCSold.Text != "")
```

This is the only line inside the IF:

```
        CATickets = double.Parse(txt_CASold.Text);
```

These would not be included:

```
        CBTickets = double.Parse(txt_CBSold.Text);
        CCTickets = double.Parse(txt_CCSold.Text);
```

When you get to here, it is telling you that if that IF statement was not true then your variables did not get initialized:

```
        CATickets = ***CATickets*** * 15.0;
        CBTickets = CBTickets * 12.0;
        CCTickets = CCTickets * 9.0;
        totalRev = CATickets + CBTickets + CCTickets;

        txt_CARev.Text = CATickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CBRev.Text = CBTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_CCRev.Text = CCTickets.ToString("C");
        txt_TotalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("C");
```

Consider changing it to the following:

```
string strCASold = txt_CASold.Text;
string strCBSold = txt_CBSold.Text;
string strCCSold = txt_CCSold.Text;

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCASold) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCBSold) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCCSold)){
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter all the appropriate values");
    return;
}

//Now, cast the string variables to doubles and assign them.
```